# can't get MySQL query to work

Tags: mysql

I am trying to create a stored procedure on a Library database for practice mainly.

But it is confusing me slightly. I am using this query to create the procedure, and it says that it is working, and yet when I then call the procedure, it is saying that the procedure does not exist. Note: I am using phpmyadmin on a web database not on a local host.

```
delimiter $$
create procedure BorrowBook(in theBookID, in theUserID)
begin
declare lim int;
declare num int;
declare loanNumber int;
declare copyNumber int;
set lim = (select Readers.Limit from Readers where Readers.id = theUserID);
set num = (select Count(*) from Loans where Loans.UserID = theUserID);
set loanNumber = (select Count(*) from Loans) + 1;
set copyNumber = (select NumberAvailable from Book where Book.id = theBookID);
if(copyNumber > 0)
if(num<lim)
then
--Add a Loan to the Loans Table
insert into Loans values(loanNumber, theBookId, theUserID, curDate(), 0);
commit;
update Book set Book.NumberAvailable = Book.NumberAvailable - 1 where Book.id = theBookID;
select 'Succesful Update';
else
rollback;
select 'Borrow limit reached';
end if;
else
rollback;
select 'No copies available';
end;
delimiter ;
```

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the `$$` after the last `end`:

```
delimiter $$
...
end; $$  <-- add $$ here
delimiter ;
```

Comment: Now it comes up with this error: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' in theUserID) begin declare lim int; declare num int; declare loanNumber in' at line 1

Are there any actual errors in the code other than this that you can see?

Comment: Try specifying the type for the parameters like `in theUserID INT`.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't it be

```
end; $$
delimiter ;
```

instead of

```
end;
delimiter ;
```